# How I can use external stylesheet for PyQT4 project?

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt4

I am just creating a remote app with pyqt4. So, there is lots of css on the UI. I was wondering how to use external stylessheets like in web apps.

For Example:

```
button_one.setStyleSheet("QPushButton { background-color:#444444; color:#ffffff; border: 2px solid #3d3d3d; width: 15px; height: 25px; border-radius: 15px;}"
                                 "QPushButton:pressed { background-color:#ccc;}")
Instead of the above code 
button_one.setStyleSheet("QPushButton.styleclass or #styleid")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to set a stylesheet on each widget. Just set one stylesheet for the whole application:

```
stylesheet = """
QPushButton#styleid {
    background-color: yellow;
}
QPushButton.styleclass {
    background-color: magenta;
}
QPushButton {
    color: blue;
}
"""

QtGui.qApp.setStyleSheet(stylesheet)
```

The qss id of a widget can be specified with `setObjectName`:

```
button_one.setObjectName('styleid')
```

The qss class can be specified with `setProperty`:

```
button_two.setProperty('class', 'styleclass')
```

For other qss selectors, see [Selector Types](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types) in the Qt docs.

Comment: This was useful to me as well - I did not know that we can use set property.

Answer (score 0):

Cool. Thank you so much for your answer. That helped me to separate my styles finally :)

Just defined all my apps styles on the external file and linked on the required page.
styleFile = "styles/remote.stylesheet"
        with open(styleFile, "r") as fh:
            self.setStyleSheet(fh.read())